# Is the companion object value of the class different from the companion object value of the instance?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm learning.

I wonder if the value of `companion object of class` and `value of companion object of created instance` are separate.

I want to change the value of companion object in a list instance created with `class Person` using companion object.

Below is the example code.

```
fun main() {
    val personlist : List<Person> = listOf(Person(1), Person(2), Person(3))
    Person.name = "ABC" // Will the name of the personlist change?
    personlist.name = "ABC" // error
}

class Person(val num: Int) {
    companion object {
        var name: String = "TEST"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why `personlist.name` would even work. You access `name` on a `List` object, not on a `Person`.

Comment: @broot It doesn't work. This is an error code. I just didn't comment it out. I want to know how to change the value of the companion object of personlist

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I meant that I don't understand why do you expect `personlist` to have any companion at all. `personlist` is a `List` object and it doesn't have a companion.

Comment: So, you mean that `personlist` itself is a `List` type object, so there is no `companion object`, and there is a `companion` object in each `index`?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes, I mean that `personlist` is a `List` and you would need to get an item from it to have a `Person` object. But no, you can't access companion object using an object instance. `Person.name` is fine, but `Person(1).name` is not. Anyway, why do you want to do this? Why not to just use `Person.name`? And why do you need to share a single "name" property between all persons? That sounds strange.

Comment: Ah... Then `personlist.get(1).name` and `personlist.name` are wrong. Does this mean that it is not possible to access an `instance` and should only be accessed by the `class name`? (`Person.name`)
I didn't know very well...

And the `name` in the code was like that because I roughly wrote the sample code.